# Circuit Lap Racing Game using Flex 4?

Tags: pointers, resources, flex4, flash-builder

Are there any resources where I can learn or possibly see a sample of a simple circuit-type top-view racing game using Flex 4? Also, please provide pointers of things to consider when planning to making something like such.

It doesn't need to be multi-player, the users will go against pre-programmed AI racers then after the race, the user's score will be submitted to an online high-score table. The submission of high scores can easily be done by calling a PHP file from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flex 4 is not for game so I don't think you will find any example

Comment: Plain AS3 project. Flex is more suited for application development.
Emanuele Feronato (www.emanueleferonato.com) has a great blog on flash game development, maybe you can find something interesting there.
wonderfl.net is also an excellent resource. I've just done a search there with the circuit keyword : http://wonderfl.net/search?q=circuit&x=0&y=0

Comment: But the problem is I don't have Flash and I'm really more of a programming guy than a designing guy so in a way, the Flash Builder 4 IDE is more friendly to my eyes since I'm familiar with the way it looks.

Comment: Yes but using Flash Builder doesn't mean you have to use Flex. You can do AS3 projects with Flash Builder